# Half disappearing line rectangle when defining base height

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, spline

I am having an issue in ArcScene. I have a spline surface representing the topography of an area, and want to create a solid fill beneath this. I can't do this form the spline layer itself or a (rectangle) polygon of the spline area. I have now tried to converted the polygon to a line feature, however, upon defining the base height (from the spline layer), only one length of the rectangle appears.

[image]

Why is this?